# mb_split not properly splitting string with backslashes

Tags: php, arrays, regex, split

here goes my first question on Stackoverflow.

When I execute the following PHP code:

```
var_dump (mb_split ("/", "2001/12/25"));
var_dump (mb_split ("\\\\", "2001\12\25"));
```

The first line gives me expected results, but not the second.

Results of the first line:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2001"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "25"
}
```

Results of the second line:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "2001
  "
}
```

Why am I not getting an array of three elements in the second line? Note the garbage characters at the end of the end of the only element of the array? Where did the other two portions of the date go? Explode seems to give the same results. I'd be willing to replace the '\'s for '/'s before running the above split, but none of the replace types of functions seem to work.

Kind regards all.

Comment: How about `var_dump (mb_split ("\\\\", "2001\\12\\25"));`? You need to escape the backslashes in the date too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting unexpected results because the backslash `\` is unescaped in your second parameter.

try

```
var_dump (mb_split ("\\\\", "2001\\12\\25"));
```

outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "2001"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "25"
}
```

Or based on the php doc for [single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

You could also simply use the single quoted version:

```
var_dump (mb_split ("\\\\", '2001\12\25'));
```

Here is the php documentation for [Escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and for [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I can't believe the time I wasted because I used double quotes instead of single. Spencer Doak answer was also correct, but found your answer to be more thorough. Thanks a bunch for the quality and speed of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `"2001\12\25"`, the backslashes in this string/date are being treated as escapes. Changing it from `"2001\12\25"` (double quotes) to `'2001\12\25'` (single quotes) should produce the desired results.